# How to plot scatterplot on top of solid line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have two pairs of x and y values, one plotted as a line plot (blue), the other as a scatter plot (red). The points overlap, and the solid blue line is plotted on top of the red dots, causing only the non-overlapping portions of the red dots to be visible. I want this to be the other way around: I want the red dots to all be *on top* of the blue line so that the red dots are all completely visible, with the blue line being obscured at the points of overlap. Any suggestions for how to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x1 = np.linspace(0,10,20)
x2 = np.linspace(0,10,500)

y1 = np.sin(x1)
y2 = np.sin(x2)

plt.plot(x2,y2, color = 'b')
plt.scatter(x1,y1,marker = 'o', s = 6, color = 'r')
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting the z-order: `plt.scatter(..., zorder=3)`. Lines default have z-order 2. The z-order defines the "layer" on which the element is drawn. First the elements with the lowest z-order are drawn, then the rest, one on top of the other.

Comment: just set `marker='*'` in plt.plot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use zorder.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x1 = np.linspace(0,10,20)
x2 = np.linspace(0,10,500)

y1 = np.sin(x1)
y2 = np.sin(x2)

plt.plot(x2,y2, color = 'b', zorder=0)
plt.scatter(x1,y1,marker = 'o', s = 6, color = 'r', zorder=1)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

From your data, you can have an option to pas `markevery` to `plt.plot`:

```
plt.plot(x2,y2, color = 'b', marker='o', markerfacecolor='r', markevery=25)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This would look even nicer with one x-value more: `x2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 501)`